# Place code after X paragraphs

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this to place code after a specified number of paragraphs in posts, but I don't know how to make in addition to the closing `</p>` also recognize `</h3>`

Thanks!

```
function adify_paragraphs($content) {
    $tmp = $content;
    $tmp = explode('</p>',$content);
    $adcode = 'additional code 1';
    $adcode2 = 'additional code 2';

    if (count($tmp)>3):
        array_splice($tmp,1,0,$adcode);
    endif;
    if (count($tmp)>9):
        array_splice($tmp,7,0,$adcode2);
    endif;
    $cc = implode('<p/>',$tmp);
    return $cc;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'adify_paragraphs');
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. To use same above process with `<h3>` you can explode/implode by `</h3>` instead of `</p>`.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I want to use </h3> and </p> in explode/implode, but I don't know how to do it. If I use </h3> instead of </p>, only place the code if there are </h3> in the post. If the post only has </p>, the additional code is not show.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution that might not be elegant, but it works. What it does is adds an extra paragraph after every 2nd paragraph, if it's not followed by H3.

```
function adify_paragraphs($content) {
    // Splitting the content into an array of paragraphs and headers.
    preg_match_all('/<h3>.*<\/h3>|<p>.*<\/p>/imU', $content, $matches);
    $count = count($matches[0]);
    if (empty($count)) {
        // Nothing to work with.
        return $content;
    }
    $p_count = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        // Increment the paragraph counter if we meet a paragraph.
        // Otherwise, reset it.
        if (strpos($matches[0][$i], '<p>') !== FALSE) {
            $p_count++;
        } else {
            $p_count = 0;
        }
        if ($p_count == 2 && strpos($matches[0][$i+1], '<h3>') === FALSE) {
            // Insert the additional code and reset the counter.
            $content = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $matches[0][$i].'<p>AD!</p>', $content);
            $p_count = 0;
        }
    }
    return $content;    
}
```

Change `2` to any other number if you need to insert your ads in a different way (it's not quite clear from your code, unfortunately).

You can see it working here: https://eval.in/521508

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try with this.